# Как избавиться от ошибки non-numeric

Tags: r

```
x<- read.table('d:\\2.csv', sep=';', header=TRUE)
x <- log(x) #логарифмируем 
x <- x[-1] #отбросим колонку с именами игроков
x <- apply(x, 2, diff) #считаем разницу между последовательными элементами
x <- t(x) #транспонируем таблицу
kmeans(x, 5, 1000000) #будем разбивать на 25 кластеров, максимум 1000000 иттераций
```

Читаю подготовленный файл - все читается без проблем.

Далее хочу сделать простое логарифмирование `x<-log(x)` и вылетает ошибка

> Error in Math.data.frame(x) :
>
> non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: X.stat1.stat2.stat4.

stat1 и т.д. - это имена колонок в файле.

Как мне привести данные исходные в порядок, чтобы не было таких ошибок?
Сама ссылка [на файл](https://yadi.sk/i/Am2OhwxgMiI5Qw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае, если числа являются символьными векторами, можно привести значения к числовым с помощью `as.numeric`:

```
> values <- c("9", "100")
> df <- data.frame(values)
> log(as.numeric(df$values))
[1] 0.6931472 0.0000000
```

В вашем конкретном случае можно попробовать так:

```
x <- read.table(file, sep=';', header=TRUE)
x <- x[-1] #отбросим колонку с именами игроков
x <- log(x) #логарифмируем 
x <- apply(x, 2, diff) #считаем разницу между последовательными элементами
x <- t(x) #транспонируем таблицу
is.na(x) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(x, is.infinite)) # Заменить все Inf на NA
is.na(x) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(x, is.nan)) # Заменить все NaN на NA
x <- na.omit(x) # Удалить строки, содержащие NA
kmeans(x, 5, 1000000) # будем разбивать на 25 кластеров, максимум 1000000 итераций
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но у меня таблица данных, 127 столбцов и 547 строк. и данные там вида real

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Приведите пример с проблемными строками в тексте вопроса. Я тестировал и с таблицей данных, но только с целыми числами. Только что попробовал с числами типа  3.45 и 6.44, тоже работает.

Comment: Подправил вопрос, теперь полная картина

Comment: Что если  `x <- x[-1]` поменять местами с `x <- log(x)`?

Comment: а логика не нарушится, просто я крайне новичек в R

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Вы ведь и так отбросите ненужные данные, а они мешают логарифмированию. Это лучшее решение в данном случае, по-моему.

Comment: Спасибо, а вот после этой строки возникает ошибка. > kmeans(x, 25, 1000000) #будем разбивать на 25 кластеров, максимум 1000000 
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Это результат логарифмирования. Что вы собираетесь делать с этими значениями? Удалить целую строку, если в одной из ячеек `NaN`, `NA` или `Inf`?

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать вот это в конечном итоге kmeans(x, 25, 1000000) #будем разбивать на 25 кластеров, максимум 1000000 иттераций, это сделать мне мешает как раз не числовые значения, как мне убрать их

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо заработало, вопрос, я получил кластерный анализ,так как мы отбросили колонку с именем, я вижу кластеры, и сколько в них элементов, а вопрос, как мне узнать имена этих элементов,

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Это уже, кажется, не относится напрямую к этому вопросу. Я вижу, что матрица/таблица/датафрейм для функции kmeans должна содержать только числовые значения. Не знаю, как вы хотите сохранить данные об игроках.